# Mongoose - Can't push a subdocument into an array in parent Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to push a subdocument(ApplicationSchema) into my Job schema. But it doesn't seem to work.

Following is my Job Schema :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var ApplicationSchema = require('./Application');

    const Job = new Schema({
      skills : {
        type : Array
      },
      active : {
        type : Boolean,
        default : false
      },
      applications: [ApplicationSchema],
      userId : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    },{timestamps : true});

    export default mongoose.model("Job", Job)
```

This is subdocument(ApplicationSchema). I have 5 more subdocuments in this schema.
I am pushing an object with a key-value pair of talentId and its value. But it doesn't work.
I get a new object in the array but the object I'm trying to push is not pushed.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var notesSchema = require('./notesSchema');
var documentSchema = require('./documentSchema');
var assessmentSchema = require('./assessmentSchema');
var interviewScheduleSchema = require('./interviewScheduleSchema');
var referenceSchema = require('./referenceSchema')

const ApplicationSchema = new Schema({
  talentId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Talent'
  },
  applicationType: {
    type: Number
  }
  notes: [notesSchema],
  documents: [documentSchema],
  assessment: [assessmentSchema],
  interviewSchedule: [interviewScheduleSchema],
  references: [referenceSchema]
},{
  timestamps: true
});

export default ApplicationSchema;
```

Following is my code in the API endpoint

```
.post((req, res, next) => {
  Job.findById(req.params.jobId)
  .then((job) => {
    if (job != null) {
      job.applications.push(req.body);
      job.save()
      .then((job) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(job);
      })
    }
    else {
      err = new Error('Job ' + req.params.jobId + 'not found')
      err.status = 404;
      return next(err);
    }
  }, (err) => next(err))
  .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

req.body contains following object

```
{ talentId: '5a813e1eb936ab308c4cae51' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with code.

I was using import and export default syntax which didn't seem work well with this.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

and

```
export default ApplicationSchema;
```

I replaced them with Common JS syntax and everything worked fine.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

and

```
module.exports = ApplicationSchema;
```

I did this for Job document file and every subdocument file and the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the id of the job document then you can push application object direct by doing the following:

```
Job.update(
    { _id: req.params.jobId }, 
    { $push: { applications: req.body} },
    callback
);
```

or you can use promise to handle this. and if you are only saving id of the application then you may want to change your job schema to store Id of the applications instead of whole application schema.

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push) carefully as this is very basic update query.

Comment: Hi Ridham -  I have tried the way you've suggested but I get the same result. I am actually storing a lot of details and not just talentId in the Application Schema. I have not showed the whole schema here as the question would become long.

Comment: make sure that you are having the exact data in req.body as per your schema? and can you show some data and what is actually being store in db?

Answer (score 0):

You have,

```
talentId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: 'Talent'}
```

But your `req.body` contains:

```
{ talentId: '5a813e1eb936ab308c4cae51' }
```

It should be:

```
{ talentId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5a813e1eb936ab308c4cae51') }
```